# Workaround a beamer bug? Section numbering is not Dewey like as it is with LaTeX

Tags: beamer

Consider the following simple Latex document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{A} \label{A}
\subsection{B}\label{B}
\subsubsection{C}\label{C}

I am in section \ref{A}, subsection \ref{B}, subsubsection \ref{C}.

\end{document}
```

The output employs Dewey like section numbering:

[image]

Now, if I convert this to beamer, something strange happens.
If the text is outside frames, i.e.,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{A} \label{A}
\subsection{B}\label{B}
\subsubsection{C}\label{C}

I am in section \ref{A}, subsection \ref{B}, subsubsection \ref{C}.

\end{document}
```

beamer cannot find the cross references at all. No matter how many times I run it through `latex`, the following error message appears:

```
 )pdfTeX warning (dest): name{C} has been referenced but does not exist, replac
ed by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{B} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced
 by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{A} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced
 by a fixed one
```

Strangely enough, the reference number appear in the output, but the nested Dewey numbering is lost.

[image]

Placing the text in a frame,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{A} \label{A}
\subsection{B}\label{B}
\subsubsection{C}\label{C}
\begin{frame}
I am in section \ref{A}, subsection \ref{B}, subsubsection \ref{C}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Make the error message go away, but the output is still different from the usual

[image]

So, is this a beamer bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You should have learned by now that code should not be enclosed between `<pre>` and `</pre>`. Select it and click the `{}` button, instead, or hit Control-K.

Comment: The `(dest)` errors are clear: if you don't use frames, `beamer` can't produce a target for the hyperlink generated by `\ref{A}` and similar. The non hierarchical numbering system seems to be a choice, not a bug.

Comment: I guess I never understood what's wrong with `<pre>` ... `</pre>`.  Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: With the suggested method you get syntax highlighting, which you don't have with `<pre>`

Answer (score 4):

There is no bug.

1. The “missing (dest)” error is due to the fact that, without a frame, `beamer` can't accommodate a target for the hyperlinks generated by `\ref`
2. The "lonely numbers” are a precise choice. You can add the usual code in the preamble to revert the decision.

Here's the example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{A} \label{A}
\subsection{B}\label{B}
\subsubsection{C}\label{C}
\begin{frame}
I am in section \ref{A}, subsection \ref{B}, subsubsection \ref{C}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I believe this is a bug, since in beamerartcile mode, you do get the usual Dewey like numbering...

Comment: @YossiGil I think `beamerarticle` doesn't do nothing with numbering which is fixed by the outer class (`article`, `book`, ...), while `beamer.cls` fixes this non nested numbering format.